# Changing one attribute of symbology, while leaving everything else alone in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I have 50 different attributes that I am symbolizing in ArcGIS Pro 2.4.   They have a variety of colors with black outlines.

How do I change the outline & transparency of 30 of these attributes at the same time without everything changing to the same color?

I could individually change all 30 but I'd like to highliht those 30 and change just the outline and transparency values,  without the colors becoming the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click the feature class in the Contents pane and open
   symbology from the context menu.
2. Shift click the first and last class from the "Primary Symbology" pane to
   highlight all values.
3. Click the "More" button in the "Primary Symbology" pane, and choose "Format
   all symbols" from the context menu.
4. Switch from gallery view to properties view in the "Format Polygon Symbols"
   pane.
5. Adjust outline color/size.
6. Click apply and then hit the back arrow in the "format polygon
   symbols" pane.

This should change the outline properties but leave the fill colors intact.

Transparency can just be adjusted using the slider in the Appearance tab in the ribbon.

Comment: That does work,  but how do I only apply those changes to a subset of the classes.   Also transparency can also be changed in 'color properties' after right-clicking on a class or subset of classes.

Comment: To change just a subset, highlight the classes you want to change (using Ctrl+click), right click and select format symbol(s) from the context menu.

Comment: Ok,  that does work for outlines,  but won't allow changes to transparencies for a subset of classes.